# Microsoft SQL Server equivalent of this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So, I have the following MySQL stored procedure and I am tasked to create this same procedure in Microsoft SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(Record1 = ''',Record1,''', IsCompatible, NULL)) AS ''',
           CONCAT(pr.ProductName,' ', pr.ProductRelease), '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  ProductCompatibility pc
  LEFT JOIN Products as pr
       on pr.id = pc.Record1;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
              'SELECT pr.id, CONCAT(pr.ProductName,'' '', pr.ProductRelease) as Product, ', @sql, '
                 FROM ProductCompatibility pc 
                 LEFT JOIN Products as pr
                    on pr.id = pc.Record2 
                 GROUP BY pc.Record2');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

the following seems to parse correctly, but when it is executed, I am getting errors with the IF conditions. What would be the correct syntax for Microsoft SQL?

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX), @finalsql varchar(MAX)

SET @sql = (SELECT  dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('MAX(IF(pc.Record1 = ''',pc.Record1,''', pc.IsCompatible,
NULL)) AS ''',
           CONCAT(pr.ProductName,' ', pr.ProductRelease), '''')) FROM   [dbo].[ProductCompatibility] pc LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Products] as pr on
pr.id = pc.Record1);

SET @finalsql = CONCAT(
              'SELECT CONCAT(pr.ProductName,'' '', pr.ProductRelease) as Product, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM compatibility_backup pc 
                 LEFT JOIN products_backup as pr
                    on pr.id = pc.Record2
                 GROUP BY pc.Record2');

EXECUTE(@finalsql);
```

Any pointers?

Comment: kindly post your error stack

Comment: Have you defined a `group_concat()` function?  It is not part of SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server does not ship with a native 'group concat' aggregation operator or equivalent. This must be added as a CLR-UDF (implementation provided by Microsoft), UDF/TVF, R-CTE, or implemented (stuffed) xml, etc. Alternatively, perform the denormalization on the client. See http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation etc for some different solutions.

Comment: I am well aware of the group_concat not being part of SQL Server. I have already taken care of define those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more digging this is the correct format for the equivalent SQL Server function:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX), @finalsql varchar(MAX)

SET @sql = (SELECT
    dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IIF(pc.Record1 = ''',pc.Record1,''', pc.IsCompatible, NULL)) AS ''',
           CONCAT(pr.ProductName,' ', pr.ProductRelease), ''''))
FROM 
    [dbo].[ProductCompatibility] pc LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Products] 
        as pr on pr.id = pc.Record1);

SET @finalsql = CONCAT(
              'SELECT CONCAT(pr.ProductName,'' '', pr.ProductRelease) as Product, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM ProductCompatibility pc 
                 LEFT JOIN Products as pr
                    on pr.id = pc.Record2
                 GROUP BY pr.ProductName, pr.ProductRelease, pc.Record2');

EXECUTE(@finalsql);
```

Turns out that I have to add a couple other columns in the group by section display the SQL entries properly. And also use @Revenant solution in using IIF instead of IF.

Answer (score 1):

As for the IF errors, consider changing them to [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) if you're using SQL Server 2012 or later or [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for lower versions.

Comment: I will look into using iif and will comment on whether or not that will work for me.

Comment: So, your suggestion in replacing the IF with IIF has gotten me further, but now have the following errors:
Column 'Products.ProductName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Column 'Products.ProductRelease' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.